# Calling max() on numpy array returns "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to call the `max` function to get the maximum numerical value in a numpy array, created using the following command:

```
x = cv2.imread("/Users/Name/Desktop/testdir/exampleImage.jpg")
max(x)
```

This returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I understand that this is an error normally returned when trying to use a numpy array in a boolean test. However, my array does not contain any boolean values, and the `max` function does not return a boolean.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You are using the Python version of `max`. It's getting the booleans when comparing elements.

Comment: If it's numpy you're using, isn't `np.max()` the method that you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

The the max() function works fine with 1d numpy arrays but for 2 or more dimensions use

```
np.max(x)
```

instead of

```
max(x)
```